# How to get image Downloadable when user click

Tags: javascript

can any one help that i want to get download image when the user click on it,

Thanks,

Comment: From what i understand, you need the browser to present a 'save file' dialog when the user clicks on an image (?), in which case, the `content-disposition` response header is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible in pure JS. You can use drag'n'drop instead.

Comment: thanks alot for quick response,i have a php based searching page that display a image now i want when ever user click the image it start directly downloading!

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not working crossbrowser with pure javascript yet. If you're focusing on new browsers you may have a look into the HTML5 features ( http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)

Else you would need to use a server side language that sends out the correct header for activating downloads on the client side. (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp Example #2)

I hope this might help you.